# MDF File not Opening in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, mdf

My database file of SQL Server 2012 cannot be opened, it causes the following error.

> Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
>   SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:903; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of page (1:903) in database ID 6 at offset 0x0000000070e000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\inventoryDB.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

I also checked it by using

```
DBCC CHECKDB(inventoryDB, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
```

But the result is given below

> DBCC results for 'inventoryDB'.
>   CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'inventoryDB'.

Is any possibilities to recover my data from that database file? I am also done many methods in many of the sites. But it not working and shows same error messages.

Comment: Oh joy, I was literally just telling somebody the importance of making proper SQL Server database backups.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yup, and verify media & check for consistency after taking the backup!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any mdf backup after this error occurred? If yes, you should try to create a table and restore from it using your backup.

Or try reading this article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/kb/2152734

See if it helps with your error.

Answer (score 0):

You've got corruption in your DB. Either the DB was corrupt before you tried working it and you didn't notice, or it was damaged in the work.

Here. We have few options.

Solution one - If you have a backup file, You can restore your database.

Solution two - If you do not have a backup file, you can use DBCC CHECKDB to repair it. (Resource : https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-repair-sql-database-using-dbcc-checkdb-command/)

Thanks :)

Comment: You seem to have posted many answers which link to this site, which has a checkered past when it comes to spam across the Stack Exchange network. Are you affiliated with the site? Please review the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)